# Why doesn't my python script keep running when I use &

Tags: linux, python, remote-access, scripting

I have my gameServer.py script running remotely through PuTTy.

gameServer.py looks like this:

```
while True :
  (( listen for packets ))
  (( send all packets to all clients ))
```

WHEN I execute the script normally:

```
./gameServer.py
```

It works perfectly but the terminal is tied up.  Naturally quitting PuTTy terminates my script.

I want to be able to close PuTTY and just have this script run perpetually so I tried:

```
./gameServer.py &
```

But that actually *does not work* and I don't understand why.  First of all its not receiving or sending any packets when run in that `&` mode, second of all it will go "+ Stopped" whenever I type enter or ANYTHING into the console.

Comment: I think you've gotten good answers to the first part (not quitting on logout) of your question, but as for the second (packets and key presses), I think we need to see some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why it would be stopping, but try

```
nohup ./gameServer.py &
```

This should cause gameServer.py to ignore the hangup signal when you disconnect PuTTY

Answer (score 3):

Try putting it in the background with the command: *bg*

```
user@rkt:~$ sleep 10
^z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 10
user@rkt:~$ bg
[1]+ sleep 10 &
user@rkt:~$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 10 &
```

Comment: +1 good old, yet almost forgotten (thanks, ubunut) unix foo

Answer (score 3):

You can **change your process to be a daemon**, then you can detouch your tty without having it killed:

```
def become_daemon():
  pid = os.fork ()
  if pid != 0: # if pid is not child...
    sys.exit(0)

  os.setsid() # Create new session and sets process group.
  pid = os.fork () # Will have INIT (pid 1) as parent process...
  if pid != 0: # if pid is not child...
    sys.exit(0)
```

and in your script simple invoke this function

You can look at this [ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66012/) for more about the ***double-fork*** mechanism and more precise implementation.

Comment: +1 for not just shouting "go to stackoverflow.com".

Answer (score 2):

Another way to log off and leave jobs running is with the "`disown <jobid>`" command. It allows you to unbind jobs from the current login session, so you can logoff.

Comment: disown -h <jobid>

Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active jobs. If the -h option is given, each jobspec is not removed from the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't aimed at answering your python problem, wouldn't have a clue where to start with that, but a temporary workaround / useful utility is called `screen`
`yum install screen` or `apt-get install screen` if you're using either Debian/Ubuntu or Redhat/Centos/Fedora will install it.
Screen provides you with a shell session that you can detach from and re-attach from without having to maintain a connection.  I pretty much use it on any box I'm connected to because if I get disconnected I don't cut off potentially damaging work in it's flow.

just run `screen` to spawn a new session, run your command and then press ctrl+a and then d (keep control held down for both letters)
To reconnect, run `screen -dr` from the command line and your screen session will attach itself to your current connection.